# Make player stick to lowering platform

Tags: physics

I want to make it so that when my cube touches the last red platform, it sticks to the platform. I also want to make it so that the lowering isn't so choppy. **See attached video.** This is my first Blender game and help would be much appreciated. Thanks!
Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hD-iqA-lWcdqBFSkiBcBhOOusGhU1Oej

Comment: Please post all relevant information about your scene in the question text like scene screenshots, settings and definitions used, etc. Attached files are useful and welcome, but don't rely on them exclusively to understand your question.

Comment: so you want the player and platform to move down faster then gravity?

Comment: I just want the player and the platform to stay together as the platform is moving down. See the attached video.